How can we explain Early effect by using Gummel-poon model in BJT?

When I read the my textbook, I find that we can use Gummel-poon model to explain Early effect, but the description is too short.

As per the site rules on citing references please [edit] the question to give the reference to the textbook which was the source of the Gummel-poon model image.

Have you read Section 7.7.2 about the Early effect?

This doesn't say that the Gummel-Poon model explains the Early effect. It says that the Gummel-Poon model can be modified to include the Early effect. (That is the model can be made to produce results that represent the behavior of the Early effect).
